# To implement the max level programmatically in condition

Tags: .net, logging, nlog

I had

```
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f1" />
```

Now I added the maxlevel. so

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxlevel="Error" writeTo="f1" />
```

I want to implement it programmatically. What I tried

```
Then in code:

var filter = new ConditionBasedFilter();
filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;
filter.Condition = "(level <= LogLevel.Info)";
var loggerRule = new LoggingRule(ruleName, LogLevel.Debug, target);
loggerRule.Filters.Add(filter);
nLogLoggingConfiguration.LoggingRules.Add(loggerRule);
```

But the filter is not working, because the result is same as if I don't add the filter. Which means whether I comment out the line `loggerRule.Filters.Add(filter);` or not, I get the same outcome.

**EDIT:**

It maybe the bug of NLOG. When you set up `filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;`
and `var loggerRule = new LoggingRule(ruleName, LogLevel.Debug, target);`.

The condition cannot be applied to the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do the following:

```
filter.Action = FilterResult.Ignore;
filter.Condition = "(level == LogLevel.Trace or level == LogLevel.Warn or level == LogLevel.Error or level == LogLevel.Fatal)"
```